# Wrong answer on Codechef despite running correctly on Pycharm

Tags: python, list, stack

I have a problem about checking valid expressions, containing "<" ">" characters and output the length of the longest expression that is valid.

My code runs correctly on Pycharm but says wrong answer in Codechef. I used a stack list to keep track of characters in an expression.

Code:

```
for i in range(int(input())):
x = input()
stack = []
count = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
  if(x[i]=="<"):
    stack.append(x[i])
  else:
    if(stack == []):
        break
    else:
      s = stack.pop()
      if(s == "<" ):
        count = count + 2
if(stack == []):
    print (count)
else:
    print ("0")
```

Comment: Well, are the tests done with the same version of Python? What are your test cases? What's the output?

Comment: according to the problem: test cases were 3 and the expressions were "<<>>","><","<>>>" with output 4,0,2.